# I don't understand why get_class_vars() is not working in php 7 and codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following class called Memo;

```
 <?php namespace App\Controllers;

 class Memo extends BaseController {

    public $from   = 'from';
    public $to     = 'to';
    public $title  = 'title';
    public $body   = 'body';
    public $is_read = false;

    public function index(){
       // nothing
    }
 }
```

I then have another controller as follows;

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Controllers\Memo;
class Office extends BaseController {
    public function index(){
       $memo_class_vars = get_class_vars('Memo');
       print_r($memo_class_vars);
       echo $memo1->from;
    }
}
```

the `$memo1->from;` works as expected and sends 'from' to output.  `print_r($memo_class_vars);` unfortunately comes up totally empty.  I cannot find out why.  Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the fully qualified named of the Memo class? Try using get_class_vars('\App\Controllers\Memo');

Comment: Indeed, that's what I missed.  Thank you.